# eclipse source/editor view is gone

Tags: java, android, eclipse, osx-mavericks

I am working on an android project. I was just trying to split the view so that I could see two files side by side, when I lost the view. Basically, I grabbed `apple.xml` file and slide it to split the screen. This normally works. But, someone bumped into me and then when I looked, the file I just moved to split was gone. So I thought I closed it by accident (as the other files were still there). So I double clicked the `apple.xml` file in package explorer, but it did not open. So I decided to close all. And then when I double click on any of my files none of them opened: java or xml. A grey view shows as if it's where the file should be. But strange enough, the outline view for the file is shown.

How do I get the view back?

Answer (score 0):

I find a workaround for the problem. I wouldn't call it a solution, so I am hoping someone who understands better can explain what happened and how to actually fix it.

**workaround**

- click on the menu window
- click on New Window
- close the old window

Comment: By the way, each time I start eclipse, I have to do this. So the original problem persists.